# Understanding the "fundamental theorem of covering spaces"

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, covering-spaces, groupoids

I ask this question because I'm quite confused about the fundamental theorem of covering spaces ;

This theorem say that under suitable hypothesis for a topological space $X$ (semi locally simply connected) we have an equivalence of categories :
$$Cov(X) \simeq [\Pi_1 (X) \to Set]$$
between the category of coverings of $X$ and the category of functors from the fundamental groupoïd of $X$ to the category of sets : we can "reverse" the point of view.

The way I understand this result is that a covering of such a space depend only on the fundamental groupoïd of the base space $X$, thus of his $2$-skeleton if $X$ is a CW-complex. In particular, Adding $n$-cells to $X$ for $n > 2$ shouldn't have any effect on a given covering (e.g. the universal one).

But on the other side, the long exact sequence of homotopy groups that is induced by a given covering of $X$ show that the higher homotopy groups (for $n > 1$) of $X$ and his covering are equal. So if we add 3-cells to "kill" $\pi_2 (X)$, this must have some effect on the universal covering, meaning that he depend on more than the 2-skeleton of $X$

What am I missing ?

Comment: If you add 3-cells to $X$, you are creating a new complex, let's call it $X'$. Since $X$ and $X'$ have isomorphic fundamental groups, their covering space **theories** are in some sense isomorphic. But that doesn't mean that their covering spaces themselves are the same.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I can see the point. It is a bit subtle though.